# How to build luasockets for lua 5.3

Tags: lua

I try to use library redis-lua, which I've downloaded here:

https://github.com/nrk/redis-lua

It fails this way:

```
Lua 5.3.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require 'redis'
table: 0x84caea0
> r = require 'redis'
> r.connect('127.0.0.1',1234)
./redis.lua:791: module 'socket' not found:
    no field package.preload['socket']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/init.lua'
    no file './socket.lua'
    no file './socket/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './socket.so'
```

redis-lua documentation proposes to use http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/

this leads me to the following page: http://files.luaforge.net/releases/luasocket/luasocket/luasocket-2.0.2/luasocket-2.0.2.tar.gz

Building these sources gives me following error:

```
debian@debian:~/luasocket-2.0.2$ make install
cd src; make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/debian/luasocket-2.0.2/src'
gcc  -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic   -c -o luasocket.o luasocket.c
In file included from luasocket.c:31:
auxiliar.h:38: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘luaL_reg’
luasocket.c:50: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘mod’
luasocket.c:60: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function
luasocket.c:62: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘func’
luasocket.c:66: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function
```

Please propose how to add socket support to lua 5.3.

Comment: The repository is now on GitHub: https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket with the newest release being 3.0-rc1.

Comment: The current version looks like it should work--does your `auxiliar.h` do `#include "lauxlib.h"` and does your `lauxlib.h` define `luaL_reg`?

Comment: `luaL_reg` was renamed to `luaL_Reg` in Lua 5.1. (But 5.1 still had a `#define` for compatibility with Lua 5.0 -- 5.2 and 5.3 don't.)

Comment: @hjpotter92 sockets 3.0 don't support LuaJIT.